# "out of racing" or "out of the races"

Tags: grammaticality

1. Until recently the feminine touch was kept out of racing.
2. Until recently the feminine touch was kept out of the races.

Can we say these sentences are correct grammatically?

Comment: What makes you think they might not be?

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/race) has '... [c] _races_ [noncount; ]plural[verb required?] : an event at which there is a series of horse races: _a trip to the races_.  I'd say a further broadening to cover the whole racing institution / industry is possible but unusual. But no 'answer' as this is opinion.

Comment: Not entirely sure what they are supposed to mean. They are correct grammatically, but depending on context the phrase "feminine touch" might be considered sexist (although it's often used ironically: using it to mean putting flowers by the racetrack would not be acceptable, but referring to female jockeys might be OK).